# SQL: IF a certain value is found ignore all the other values given for a ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

**SQL Server:**

The table given has one column with IDs, one column with integer values and one column with the date and time when the value was given to an ID. So one ID can have multiple corresponding values.

**Example**:

```
id  Value  datetime     
---|-----|------------------------
1  | 10  | 04/03/2009 10:12:33.000
2  | 13  | 05/02/2009 11:02:03.000
1  | 20  | 10/10/2009 13:22:45.000
1  | 15  | 12/03/2010 15:12:33.000
2  | 19  | 25/05/2009 10:12:33.000
2  | 17  | 09/06/2009 17:18:45.000
```

If the value 20 is found for a ID ignore every other row with that same ID. Otherwise show the last value given for an id.

**Result:**

```
id  Value  datetime     
---|-----|------------------------
2  | 17  | 09/06/2009 17:18:45.000
```

Comment: Use a Simple where condition with TOP(1)

Comment: But what do I do when I have more than two IDs. I want to return every ID with it's last given value and ignore it completely when one of the values is 20.

Comment: You can post your expected result in case of more IDs for ease.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter out with `NOT EXISTS` and rank with `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( id INT, v INT, d DATETIME )
INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 1, 10, '2009-03-04 10:12:33.000' ),
        ( 2, 13, '2009-02-05 11:02:03.000' ),
        ( 1, 20, '2009-10-10 13:22:45.000' ),
        ( 1, 15, '2010-03-12 15:12:33.000' ),
        ( 2, 19, '2009-05-25 10:12:33.000' ),
        ( 2, 17, '2009-06-09 17:18:45.000' );


WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY d DESC ) AS rn
               FROM     @t t
               WHERE    NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                                     FROM   @t
                                     WHERE  id = t.id
                                            AND v = 20 )
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    cte
    WHERE   rn = 1
```

Comment: Thank you! That will do the job.

Comment: How can I also return the record that met the condition?
In this case, the result will be
id 1 value 20
and
id 2 value 17

Comment: @JumanaAlhaddad, you can just add the following to the end of the query

`union
select *, null as rn from @t where v = 20`

Answer (score 0):

Hope you use `NOT IN` or `LEFT JOIN` to filter the condition.

Can you try the query below:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM YourTable WHERE Id NOT IN (
SELECT Id FROM YourTable WHERE Value = 20)
ORDER BY Value DESC
```

Sample execution with the data:

```
DECLARE @YourTable TABLE (id INT,  Value INT, datetime   DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @YourTable (id, Value, datetime)
SELECT 1 , 10 , '2009-03-04 10:12:33.000' UNION
SELECT 2 , 13 , '2009-02-05 11:02:03.000' UNION
SELECT 1 , 20 , '2009-10-10 13:22:45.000' UNION
SELECT 1 , 15 , '2010-03-12 15:12:33.000' UNION
SELECT 2 , 19 , '2009-05-25 10:12:33.000' UNION
SELECT 2 , 17 , '2009-06-09 17:18:45.000' 

SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM @YourTable WHERE Id NOT IN (
SELECT Id FROM @YourTable WHERE Value = 20)
ORDER BY Value DESC
```

Comment: But this won't return the last given value for every Id when I have more than 2 IDs. Additonally I have to filter somehow for the last date and time for an ID.

Answer (score 0):

Use ROW_NUMBER and PARTITION  for group by ID and select last insetred value by datetime in desc order.

```
    select id, value, datetime from (
         select ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION by id Order by id,datetime desc) as row_rank, id, value, datetime
         from tbl_1
    ) as A
    where row_rank=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Top 1 * 
FROM @YourTable 
Group by id, Value, datetime 
Having Value<20 
ORDER BY Value DESC
```

Comment: At-least a minimal explanation of the code would be great.